# How to create 2 active relationship between 2 tables

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables and 2 of the column have the same values (Time , Value)
Table 1

| Time | y | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 am | 1 | 2 |
| 9:00 am | 3 | 3 |
| 10:00 am | 5 | 4 |
| 11:00 am | 7 | 1 |

Table 2

| Time | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 am | ABC | 1 |
| 9:00 am | DEF | 3 |
| 10:00 am | GHI | 2 |
| 11:00 am | ERQ | 4 |

In a powerBi, I create 1 line charts with Table 1, x-axis is Time, y-axis is y-value and legend is 'value'.
And I have a table widget for my 'Table 2'.

So I have a relationship between Table1 and Table 2 so that when I click a time in the chart, the table will filter to the value of the clicked time.

How can I add a 2nd active relationship so that when I click 1 of the value in the line chart (the legend), the Table widget 's data will be filtered to the clicked legend too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in Power BI you introduce "dimension" tables to apply filters to, and then use relationships to flow the filters to the desired tables.  EG:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not how **tables** work:

If you select one element of a column, e.g. Time = 8:00, the whole row is selected: y = 1 and Value = 2. You can't select the first row of column *Time* and the third row of column *Value* simultaneously. This is why it makes no difference if you click on a data point or a legend item.

If you want to see both the outcome of filtering *Table 2* by *Time* and filtering *Table 2* by Value you have to create another reference to Table 2

```
Table 3 = 'Table 2'
```

and set the relation between the *Value* columns:

[image]